# RequireJS loadd predefined jQuery with URL args, Firefox doesn't

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, requirejs

I used RequireJS to load dependencies in my project, since jQuery already import before RequireJS. So I follow the guide like below:

```
var jQuery = window.jQuery, paths = {};

if (!jQuery) {
   paths.jquery = 'jquery-1.11.1.min';
} else {
   define('jquery', function() {
    return jQuery;
});
}
requirejs.config({  // other dependencies
   urlArgs : "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
})
```

This works fine in Firefox. But in IE8, it will load jQuery twice, load the jquery.js?bust=1234345667
How can I avoid this in IE8?

Comment: If the answer you posted is the solution, then there is something which you are not showing in your question that is *essential* to your problem. Putting an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question would help: reduce your code to what reproduces the problem and then put *this* in the question. For a question about loading this means all the relevant `<script>` tags and the code that starts RequireJS.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I put the whole code inside jQuery ready function, then everything goes fine. don't if this is the right solution.

```
$(function(){
   var jQuery = window.jQuery, paths = {};

if (!jQuery) {
  paths.jquery = 'jquery-1.11.1.min';
} else {
 define('jquery', function() {
  return jQuery;
 });
}
requirejs.config({  
     // other dependencies

    urlArgs : "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
 })

})
```